# Let B be an open, connected set in the complex plane where $0\in B$. Consider a holomorphic $f$ from B to B that is unbounded and bounded such that...

Tags: complex-analysis

I was tasked with the following:
Let $B$ be an open, connected set in the complex plane where $0\in B$. If $f:B\rightarrow B$ is holomorphic and $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$, is it true that $f(z)=z$? Treat $B$ in the bounded and unbounded cases separately.

So I have proven the statement true in the bounded case and I am looking for a counterexample in the unbounded case. Does anyone have any counterexamples that could work here?

Comment: $f(z)= \sin z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example: $B=\mathbb{C}$ and $f(z)=z^2+z$. Or any other polynomial where the free coefficient is $0$ and the coefficient of $z$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Take $B=\Bbb C$ and $f(z)=e^z-1$. More generally, take $f(z)=z+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nz^2$ for any power series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nz^2$ whose radius of convergence is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more general answer: the theorem is true even if $B$ is unbounded, provided that $\mathbb{C}-B$ contains more than one point; actually, the implication goes both ways.

To prove the claim, note that the condition is equivalent to requiring the universal cover of $B$ to be the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$.

- The universal cover is $\mathbb{D}$: $f$ must be the identity

Let $\pi:\mathbb{D}\to B$ be the covering map (which we suppose wlog sends $0$ to $0$). Now we have, by the lifting property, the existence of a map $\tilde f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ such that $\pi\circ \tilde f=f\circ \pi$ and $\tilde f(0)=0$. Differentiating this in $0$ we get $\pi'(0)\tilde f'(0)=f'(0)\pi'(0)$ and so $\tilde f'(0)=1$. Thus $\tilde f$ is the identity by Schwarz's lemma and the result follows.

- The universal cover is $\mathbb{C}$: $f$ is not necessarily the identity

If the universal cover *is* $\mathbb{C}$, the set is either the punctured plane or the plane itself. If it is the punctured plane, let $B=\mathbb{C}-\{z_0\}$. Then $e^z-z_0$ is a map satisfying the hypoteses and $f\neq z$.  If $B=\mathbb{C}$ the same map gives the result.